# Optimize real-world experiment with discrete variable

Tags: experimental-physics

I have a system to test, and I must choose the value of variable that optimize the response of this system.
Let me say that I have 7 variable, each of them setted at 3 different level, with a full factorial experiment I must compute 2187 experiments, this is impossible in the real world. I could use a fractional factorial experiment, but the number ov experiment will be high in every case. So, I think about euristic optimization, usually these method will be used in a software, but I would like to use it in real world. So, I'm thinking about three method that could be feasible:

- Genetic optimization: I could start with 15 experiment with the variables near-random: random, but checked to not have two solution much near each other. I think that in 3 or 4 generations (so, 45 to 60 experiments) I will reach a satisfactory solution;
- Simulated annealing: I start with only one random solution, and then I explore other solutions using the simulated annealing theory;
- Anto colony optimization: I read it could be a feasible way to arrive at a satisfactory solution, I never tried it so I don't know right now how it works

The problem with simulated annealing and ant colony is that I don't know how much experiment will take to give me a satisfatory result, but I could think that could be less than 60.

there exist other method to arrive at an optimal or near-optimal problem, with the less possible testing?

Comment: I assume these are simulations, not physical experiments? How long does one run take? I've used GA or gradient descent, but usually a partial factorial experiment is most often used. A 2 level 7 factor can be run in 64 or fewer runs, when you've found the important factor(s) run a smaller experiment with more levels to fine tune your answer

Comment: These are physical experiment, the 7 factor are 7 parts that compose my system, that I can assemble and test

Comment: I'd start with a a 2 level screening experiment, which could be as few as 8 runs, and then investigate the important factors. Again, how long does a test take?

Comment: So, your advice is to go with the fractional factorial way? The experiment didn't take much time, no more than 2 minutes, but to set-up each experiment require more or less half hour

Comment: Yup. GA is inefficient, but robust (when done properly), a DOE is efficient and fairly robust.

Comment: Good I will try this way, thank you